# How to suppress an unwanted external Autodiscover lookup?

Tags: exchange, outlook, autodiscovery

In a small network with Exchange 2007, when starting Outlook 2010 (and once in a while afterwards), users get a prompt to confirm that it's safe to get account configuration information from `cpanelemaildiscovery.cpanel.net/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` (I could read in a couple of forums that there is a bug in cpanel, but that's beside the point.)

I'm puzzled because I can't find any autodiscover DNS entries anywhere, neither internally nor externally. The only hint is that we use an external hosting company for our website and for one single email address, which runs on cpanel. So I guess that Outlook makes an external DNS query to test all entries? It reates a lot of confusion for the users and frankly I'm not too happy that the external hosting company gets contacted by all our users.

How can I suppress this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: What does an [MX Toolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/) lookup for your domain return?

Comment: It lists the correct 3 MX adresses we use. Nothing pointing to cpanel.net.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are limited on a Hosted Exchange.

Having said that, you can test your Exchange Autodiscover services externally using ExRCA tool from Microsoft.

https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

- Check exchane autodiscover.
- Plugin your values. You can paste the ExRCA output here with return codes for further analysis. Please obfuscate your domain and other private data before posting in a public forum.

hth

Comment: It's not a hosted exchange, I have full control over it. The test above fails everything (no autodiscover found), except for the DNS name resolution which is correct.

Comment: What version of exchange are you running ?

Comment: Can you run the following commands on exchange shell

Comment: Get-autodiscovervirtualdirectory | fl and get-webservicesvirtualdirectory | fl

Comment: It's 2007. I can run the 2 commands but the results are too large to be posted here. Anything in particular? I don't see any reference to cpanel.net or any other outside domains.

Comment: Are the following fields populated when you run the 2 commands : InternalURL and ExternalURL ?

Comment: The first command has the 2 fields blank. The second has just the InternalUrl, which points to https://mx.externaldomain.com/ews/exchange.asmx

Answer (score 1):

There is a very good chance that the actual Domain name is pointing to a web server that is using cpanel. If you don't provide the auto discovery records at the registrar level or in the cpanel account then you do get this message from the cpanel autodiscovery service. I have resolved this issue by creating an a record for autodiscovery pointing to the ip address of the exchange server.

Comment: Did you add that to the external DNS?